# Меню или кнопка для iOS отображающиеся на всех View Controller

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

При создании приложения в XCode для iOS на Swift 4 возникла проблема , понадобилось создание кнопки на всех существующих View Controller. У меня их очень много более 100 даже не спрашивайте почему так много , в итоге вручную их расставить будет очень трудно. Хотелось бы узнать возможно ли создать меню или кнопку которая автоматически появится на всех существующих View Controller?

Comment: Что должно происходить при нажатии на эту кнопку? Что-то специфичное для каждого контроллера?

Comment: Нет это обычная UIButton с одной функцией для всех контроллеров

Answer (score 0, accepted):

можешь сделать BaseViewController (наследника UIViewController) в котором добавить кнопку и наследовать все свои контроллеры от этого BaseViewController-a. Соответственно кнопка появится в дочерних контроллерах.

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {
       // код добавления кнопки где то здесь
   }

class AnotherViewController: BaseViewController {
       // этот контроллер уже содержит кнопку
   }
```

Comment: если не трудно то как вообще создать BaseViewController и наследовать его к UIViewController? в интернете особо внятной информации не нашёл

Comment: расширил ответ. но если вы пока не понимаете таких базисных вещей, лучше вам наверно поучить матчасть